# Creating Symbolic Links With Matlab/Octave

Tags: matlab, octave, symlink

I'm optimising a Matlab code that grabs files from an external source, modifies the file name and reads the data from the file. Currently, this is accomplished by copying the files to another directory and saving with the modified file name. I'd like to just create symbolic links with the modified file names with Matlab instead of copying the files. Can this be done in Matlab, and if yes, how?

Comment: You can issue a shell command from Matlab using `system`. So build the appropriate command string, say `str`, and then use `system(str)`

Comment: why don't you just read the file? Why do you need to copy to another place to read it? Being able to copy the file means that you are already capable of reading the file.

Comment: @carandraug, yeah I know. This is code a friend wrote and it makes use of some API that he believes necessitates it done this way.
@LuisMendo Thanks, `system()` works well.